# SoundPool Not Playing after Two Presses

Tags: android

Every time I press the two buttons for the SoundPools, the audios does not play after I click the buttons two times during testing the app. Here is my code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        turnOff = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        sirenStop = turnOff.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ecto_siren_stop, 1);
        gbTheme = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ghostbusters_theme);
        loop = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        sirenLoop = loop.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ecto_siren_time_loopable, 1);
        Button on = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnOnButton);
        on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sirenLoop = loop.play(sirenLoop, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1);
            }
        });
        Button off = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnOffButton);
        off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loop.pause(sirenLoop);
                sirenStop = turnOff.play(sirenStop, 1,1,1,0,1);
            }
        });
```

I want the two audios to play every time I press the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your code like that:

```
off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loop.pause(sirenLoop);
            turnOff.play(sirenStop, 1,1,1,0,1); //Here
        }
});
```

Comment: It looks the same as my original code to me

Comment: It is not same please check again. ''sirenStop ='' remove unnecessary integer.

Comment: I see, sorry I missed that

Comment: Please let me know if it is working or not. If everything is okay please vote and close the post.

Comment: It works, now I can't stop the first SoundPool from playing when I press the off button.